# How to create a centered and equal sized tabs, Tab Bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to create a Tab bar in which the size of the tabs are independent of the size of the screen, using the default tab bar creates a very long tab when running on a desktop, i want all the tabs to be the same size and be centered as if it were a Row

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  isScrollable: false,
```

---

```
TabBar(
              isScrollable: false,
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              labelStyle:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              labelColor: Colors.black,
              controller: _controller,
)
```

make :  **isScrollable : false,**
now you will have the equal size tabs